# Facing java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError on trying to load OpenCV with Java 11

Tags: java, macos, opencv, java-8, java-11

We are using OpenCV in our test automation framework. The version we are using is `3.2.0-1`

This code:

```
// load OpenCV library
if (Boolean.parseBoolean(getProperty(SystemPropertyConstants.OPENCV_ENABLED_KEY, "false"))) {
    OpenCV.loadShared();
    OpenCV.loadLocally();
    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
}
```

throws error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java320 in java.library.path: 
    [/Users/myuser/Library/Java/Extensions, 
     /Library/Java/Extensions, 
     /Network/Library/Java/Extensions, 
     /System/Library/Java/Extensions, 
     /usr/lib/java, .]
```

only when I use `jdk 11`. If I use `jdk 1.8` it works fine.

Are there any known issues for opencv with latest Java versions? Or is there any workaround to get this working?

Comment: I'm using a MacOS machine so will a DLL work in that case?

Comment: On MacOS it would be `dylib` then. I primarily meant the native library is present on any of those paths?

Comment: Nope I could not find any dylib file. If that's the case then I wonder how it's working fine when I switch to JDK1.8

Comment: 1. Use of debugger with each case would let you know the exact difference. 2. I doubt this could possibly be the area where accessing resources has got an update with Java 9 release introducing modularisation.